# Update Primary Key with NVARCHAR Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database with a table called `Lineitem`. This table has a primary key field `Code` and currently has more than 1,000,000 rows.

I need to update the primary key with a NVARCHAR that starts from `Li000000001` and that increments like this `Li000000002`, `Li000000003` etc.

How can I do this technically please?

Comment: Maybe technology-specific solution is required, please add the tag of what you are using (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, ...).

Comment: "... with a row of more than 1000000." -- More than 1000000 *what*? Columns? Bytes? Stones? Kittens? Your question is unclear. [Edit] it and include a [example], i.e. the schema as `CREATE TABLE` statements, sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements and the desired result with that sample data. Also tag the DBMS you're using and what you've tried so far and what the problem with this was.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL 2012. row means already existing records in my table "LineItem". The table has 12 columns, Code, voucher,article, unitamount, quantity, UOM, Totalamount, taxableamount,tax, taxamount, calculatedcost,remark. Code is the primary key to be updated to new values sequentially like  Li000000001,Li000000002.....

Comment: @AyalewDerese, Edit your question, add essential details. Don't use comments for that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use:

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value (-> this is probably your existing `Code` column)
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.LineItem
ADD AlphaCode AS N'Li' + RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(ID AS NVARCHAR(9)), 9) PERSISTED
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `LineItem`, SQL Server will automatically increase your `Code` value (as it has so far), and `AlphaCode` will contain values like `Li000000001`, `Li000000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.